# perl cgi form processing

Tags: perl

I am working on a file and I am trying to understand how to process a form in hopes of passing a hidden field. for simplicity, lets say i want my scipt to simply show the value of the hidden field when it is first presented to the user, incremented by one, and after it is 'submitted', the new script displayed with the updated hidden field. I am trying to gain insight on the explicit procedure so i can apply it to one of my current projects.
I have searched the web but most examples simply confuse me, can anyone chime in?

Comment: More information would be helpful - do you have some perl code already written?  What modules have you looked into using, if any?  What is your HTML?

Comment: Please stop using the dirty old CGI.pm. Use instead a modern and clean web engine such as [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) or [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Values submitted by the form can be retrieved using the [`CGI`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI) module (since you haven't shown any code, I don't know whether you're using `CGI` or attempting to handle the CGI interactions by hand; if you're doing it by hand, You're Doing It Wrong) and its `param` method.

Given the HTML form:

```
<form action='my_script.cgi' method=POST>
  <input type=hidden name=hidden_field value=1>
  <input type=submit>
</form>
```

You can retrieve the hidden value with (in `my_script.cgi`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new;
my $hidden_value = $q->param('hidden_field');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write the value of the hidden field to a cookie. Each time you refresh or revisit the same webpage, your script can read the cookie into the hidden variable and increment it by one. The following example uses a variable instead of a hidden field in the form.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#countvisits.cgi
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw(:standard -debug);
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

#declare variables
my ($count, $C_record);

#Create a new CGI object
my $cgi = new CGI;

#Read the cookie
#assign input to variable
$count=$cgi->cookie('count');

$count++;

#create cookie
$C_record = cookie(-name => "count",
                 -value => $count,
                 -expires => "6M");


#send cookie to browser
print header(-cookie => $C_record);

#create Web page
print "<HTML>\n";
print "<HEAD><TITLE>Jubilee Book Club</TITLE></HEAD>\n";
print "<BODY>\n";
print "<H1 ALIGN=center>Hello!<BR>\n";
print "You have been here $count times.</H1>\n";
print "</BODY></HTML>\n";
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, that is a very clever way of going about it, but i am restricted to using form processing, is there a way where it is possible to do the same using forms? I am new to perl so i am trying to understand what would be used in the form action call, if the hidden field needs to be decoded upon passing etc.. I appreciate anything you can find, even any links that provide well explained articles. I have been hammering away for a couple days now, i have my form and values to be passed, i just dont know how to pass them.

Comment: The answer by @Dave Sherohman looks good to me. Make sure your hidden field has a name attribute. When you submit the form, the values of any of the form fields that have name attributes can be retrieved by the script named in the action attribute, via the param method of a CGI object.